# Azure CDN fails with "That action isn't allowed" when enabling HTTPS for a custom domain

Tags: azure-cdn

I am attempting to enable HTTPS on a custom domain for Azure CDN, but both `az` PowerShell and the API fail when I try to do this programmatically.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "That action isn’t allowed in this profile."
  }
}
```

First I tried through PowerShell. Note: that this produces a rather useless error unless you use the `-Debug` switch -

```
Enable-AzCdnCustomDomainHttps -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ProfileName $profileName -EndpointName $endpointName -CustomDomainName $customDomainName -Debug
```

Noticing that the version of `az` PowerShell that I have installed was using API version **2019-04-15**, I began to investigate whether or not there was a newer version of API available, and there is - **2019-12-21**. Using this latest API, I ran the HTTP request outside of PowerShell, but this led to the exact same error.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{ResourceGroup}}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/{{CdnProfile}}/endpoints/{{CdnEndpoint}}/customDomains/{{CdnCustomDomain}}/enableCustomHttps?api-version=2019-12-31' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{BearerToken}}' \
--data-raw '{
  "certificateSource": "Cdn",
  "certificateSourceParameters": {
    "certificateType": "Shared",
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.CdnCertificateSourceParameters"
  },
  "protocolType": "IPBased"
}'
```

Digging further, it looks like Microsoft acknowledged the issue in August last year, but then swiftly closed [the issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9654) without actually fixing it or offering a workaround.

Has anyone been able to come up with a workaround for this? It seems unfathomable that Microsoft would just not bother to fix this, and it's unsustainable to rely on manual intervention every time we create a new CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9654 , same issue appears on a UI, so it seems to be a bug in Azure Resource Manager.

On UI, the solution was to open in Incognito mode. Perhaps this is an issue with a session, so logging off an on again in CLI should help likewise.